# SSRS 2008 Multi value parameter data driven subscription

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an SSRS report that uses a multiple value parameter. The available values is single column data set. e.g.

AccountNumber
AccountName 
Address 
Sales

It's just a list of column heading names.(Each column in the report has a visibility toggle whether the column name was selected as part of the multi value parameter)

The report works fine as a regular report running on demand, and a regular subscription (just selecting which columns I want for various subscriptions).

I need to do a data driven subscription for the same report. As part of the DDS, I pass in the columns I want for this particular subscription: 
SELECT 'AccountNumber,AccountName,Sales' as columns

I get the value from the database for the 1 parameter. The subscription errors. (I don't have access to get the specific errors at this point). If I specify multiple columns as a static parameter it doesn't work as well. If i specify 1 column the report works.

Thanks in advance for help !

**Update**
I was able to get semi workarounds 2 ways. 
 1. Instead of getting my report's parameter Available Values from a database query, I specified values, which wasn't a problem in this example. Then the typical drop down multi value select box works in a data driven. You would think a query could do the same thing since it talks to the database in the DDS query & in a regular subscription, why not in a data driven subscription? 
 
 2. Before i did the above, I added another row in my parameter data set query called "Default". I then made a hidden dummy parameter saying iif the input was default then use a hard coded column list, otherwise use whatever was entered. Then I could enter 1 value in my DDS of "Default". I then had to adjust the column visibility formulas to work for my dummy parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Get the value from DB as union instead of comma separated like

```
SELECT 'AccountNumber' AS [Columns]
UNION
SELECT 'AccountName' AS [Columns]
UNION
SELECT 'Sales' AS [Columns]
```

Instead of getting from query -

```
SELECT 'AccountNumber,AccountName,Sales' as columns
```

Comment: I tried that as well, that passes each row as 1 parameter and runs the report separately each time. So I would get a report with just the AccountNumber field. Then a 2nd report with just the AccountName field, and so on.

Comment: try to set default value as all in report like & set default in subscription  SELECT 'AccountNumber' AS [Columns]
UNION
SELECT 'AccountName' AS [Columns]
UNION
SELECT 'Sales' AS [Columns]

Comment: That was a good thought, I thought that might do it. However when I give the parameter a default list in addition to the multi value select (Available Values box), it does not give me the checkbox to "Use Default" once I go in to setup the data driven subscription.